# Customise FAB in BottomAppBar for iOS

Tags: ios, floating-action-button, material-components-ios

Just read [an article about customising BottomAppBar in Material Components for Android](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708) and now I wonder how to do the same for iOS.

Actually I need to change `fabCradleDiameter`, `fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius`, `fabCradleVerticalOffset` and FAB radius.

Article above shows that on Android it's done via app:* parameters in some layout xml. But there is no such xml in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

look to do it in iOS touch to create the component in execution time, to do it you do it in the following way:

```
 var bottomAppBar: MDCBottomAppBarView {
            let bottomAppBar = MDCBottomAppBarView()
            // background color Bottom App Bar
            bottomAppBar.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "Teal")
            // Image floatingButton
            bottomAppBar.floatingButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "CloudUpload"), for: .normal)
            // Background color floatingButton
            bottomAppBar.floatingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Gray600")
            // here you define the size of the bottom app bar, in my case I define the size based on a view that I added to the ViewController
            let size = bottomAppBar.sizeThatFits(self.containerView.bounds.size)
            bottomAppBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height) 

            // The following lines of code are to define the buttons on the right and left side
            let barButtonLeadingItem = UIBarButtonItem(
                image: UIImage(named:"IconName"), // Icon
                style: .plain,
                target: self,
                action: #selector(self.onMenuButtonTapped))

            let barButtonTrailingItem = UIBarButtonItem(
                image: UIImage(named: "IconName"), // Icon
                style: .plain,
                target: self,
                action: #selector(self.onNavigationButtonTapped))
            bottomAppBar.leadingBarButtonItems = [barButtonLeadingItem]
            bottomAppBar.trailingBarButtonItems = [barButtonTrailingItem]
            return bottomAppBar
        }
 // Add bottombar to view
 self.containerView.addSubview(bottomAppBar)
```

**NOTE:** the above code is tested in **Swift 5.0**

Comment: There are only two properties for changing the floating action button size, how to set custom size

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning from where the "MBCBottomAppBarView" is coming from: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/tree/develop/components/BottomAppBar